# Transfering content from my local docker environment to production

Tags: craft4, docker

For the second time, I've created a website with CraftCms. This time, I used my windows computer to setup the project but I had to use docker. Fyi, I'm not experienced with docker, but I was experienced enough to setup my project and start it.

However, at this moment, my site has been deployed on the production server and after importing the sql file I made right before deploying it, I still had no content at all.. (I'm not even sure if the content is included in the sql file..). But it looks like I'm having difficulties rn..

My local has the content but no static images (I'm only interessted in the content), but When I login, I get an error message "Unable to verify your data submission". There is no css working on the admin page.

The weird thing is that when I look my .env file, my db credentials are set to default. After I filled out the correct credentials and restart my docker container. The credentials in the env file are resetted.. This is probably because of an error inside a docker config file but I have no clue which file..

Anyone that has an idea what it could be or maybe that can give me another explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, your docker config might miss some volumes. You could have a look if your config, storage, templates, translations and web are properly shared between your machine and the docker container. Same for the `.env` file. You can do this by defining [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Without a close look at your exact docker config or docker-compose file there's no real way to answer that.

That said, maintaining a docker setup yourself can be tedious. If you're not invested in spending a substantial amount of your time in fixing this kind of stuff, I can wholeheartedly recommend to use [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#craft-cms). It uses docker, but abstracts away a lot of this stuff. At the same time you get commands to open your db, to [import](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/database-management/#database-imports) and [export](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/cli/#exporting-a-database) your DB and a lot more. And you have an online documentation, that helps you to do 95% of your daily tasks.